# how to plot an edgelist as a network graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, networking, social-networking

I have an edgelist file like 'test.edgelist'. I want to draw it as a network such as nodes and edges. How to do it in matlab? The graph must represent a network graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the `bioinformatics` toolbox?

In that case:

Create a sparse adjacency matrix from the edgelist:

```
Adj_mat = sparse(from_list, to_list,1,nb,nb);
```

Thereafter, create a `biograph` object:

```
bg = biograph(Adj_mat, "some properties");
h = view(bg);
```

This will create a directed graph. If you want an undirected graph:

```
Adj_Tri = tril(Adj_mat + Adj_mat'); 
bg = biograph(Adj_Tri,[],'ShowArrows','off','ShowWeights','off');
h = view(bg);
```